# type error: string indices must be integers when parsing JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, github

I have the following code pulling in a commit log using the GitHub API.

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/ErinBailey/cs399-social/commits', auth=('cs399contributions', 'contributions399'))
    #convert JSON string into Python nested dictionary/list
input_log = json.loads(r.text)
user_ids = [x['committer']['id'] for x in input_log if x['committer'].get('id')]
output_json = json.dumps(user_ids, indent=4)
print output_json
```

The error I am running into is type error: string indices must be integers.
I suspect it is because I am using a list iterator to traverse a dictionary but I am not sure how to circumvent this. What I am trying to do is pull out a list of "ID"s of all the committers on the log.

Comment: You can use `r.json()` rather than `json.loads(r.text)` here; this takes (much) better care of correct codec handling.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, not with anonymous credentials anyway. The API call produces a list of dictionaries, all of which have a `committer` key that references another dictionary.

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of your error?

Comment: Well, i get the same error exactly when there is no credentials (as Martijn noted) - because the returned json does not contain what you expect - so maybe you didn't supply them yourself?