# Using Python and GitHub's API : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, github

I am trying to use GitHub's JSON API to pull in a list of all pull requests that contain assignees (so I can send them a message to resolve their pull requests).

I feel like I am close with the following code, but maybe I am not parsing the JSON correctly? any help would be appreciated.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<repo>/<repoguide>/pulls?" 

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <mastertoken>',
  'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
  'page': 'page=5&per_page=100'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
response = requests.get(url).json()
for obj in response:
   
    assignees = obj['assignees']
    for assignee in assignees :
      name = assignee['login']
      url = obj['html_url']
      print('/md Hello {0}, there is a GitHub issue that needs your attention. For more information see [here]({1}).'.format(name,url))
```

Error:

```
    assignees = obj['assignees']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I don't understand what this error means or how to resolve it. Is it pulling a string vs dictionary? Sorry, this is my first time writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55785972/6309), if you get "`string indices must be integers`" on
`obj['assignees']`, it means obj is a string, not a dictionary.

Since a [similar error was tricky to be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29705260/6309), I would print, for debug, the value of `response`, to check its nature.